# Xcode UIImageView won't link to the code

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a problem:

I need to insert a `UIImageView` into my application  that changes images each time. The code I have written is correct, but the `UIImageView` box I dragged on my view in storyboard won't link to the code. I drag the blue line on the codes but it just does not link.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1
```

Can you help me????

Answer (score 1):

Two possible things:

1. are you also adding it in your @Interface in the .h file? like below:

   ```
   @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
       IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;
   }
   ```
2. Also, after you do this make sure you are linking your UIImage View to your files owner in the .xib file. control drag from "File's Owner" right into the image view.

I don't have a ton of iOS experience, but these are two pretty common problems.

Comment: I am usingo stoiyboard not nib

Answer (score 0):

h file
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1

m file
@synthesize image1;

Link should show up.